# Slider in WPF Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set the Value of the Slider to 1.0 but when in debugger, I can see that after the assignment like:

```
surfaceSlider.Value = 1.0;
```

the value stays at the current value (0.0).

Any ideas why I can't set that dependency property?

Comment: Is the surfaceSlider a customized control or is it out of the box?

Comment: out of box, SurfaceSlider is part of the Surface SDK

Answer (score 0):

WPF Slider Value property is dependency property, this will accept the values.

I think you are creating a custom control with a dependency property named "Value". Make sure your setter property is public and OwnerType is your class.

Comment: No this is not a custom control. SurfaceSlider is a control that is part of the Surface SDK